# While riding bike , Pressing clutch turn off the motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, acceleration, choke

My Motorcycle Suzuki sling shot, When riding the motorcycle at the traffic time when **pressing the clutch** it suddenly

> turn off the motorcycle

But when **put ON the choke** and riding motorcycle

> it never turn off the bike

What is the main cause of this problem.

The Motorcycle having the enough fuel for riding. But can't predict. I am very new and not knowing much information about Motorcycle controls. Guide me

Thanks

Saravanan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If when you put the choke on the engine does not quit, it indicates the engine is running too lean (not getting enough fuel).

This can be caused by a carburetor that is dirty or needs to be adjusted, an air leak between the carburetor and the engine, or bad/old fuel.

Comment: Hey friend thanks your suggestion. I will check it out the air leakage between the engine and carburetor and then let you know. And I used power petrol(fuel).

Comment: and ofcourse i will check the adjustment/Dirty of carburetor.

Comment: That is absolutely correct @CharlieRb. Thanks for your answer . Feeling good ;)